# Dark mode and contrast

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode

Text in dark mode are not contrasty enough. On examination I noticed the text colour isn't white but near white (235 vs 255 rgb value). can we make the text color 100% white `#fff or rgb(255,255,255).`

Answer (score 11):

235, or #EB, on a black background, has enough contrast to be considered accessible. It rates at **17.61**:1, which is far beyond the AAA rating of 7:1.

See WebAIM for more details: https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=EBEBEB&bcolor=000000

That said, if you personally feel that dark mode doesn't have enough contrast, there is always light mode; which, in general, is easier on the eyes to read.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. do know what's the font size of normal text for calculation? I assume(based on inspect element) its 18px without bold. whereas on SO its 15px. Still it won't go below 7:1 I assume.

Comment: They define "large text" as 18.66px *and* bold, or 24px and *not* bold; or larger.